# Authentication with Cognito - where to find logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

We have 2 React Native app are using AWS Cognito for authentication. We use library react-native-aws-cognito-js in our code. The apps are working fine until these 2 days. Apps are experiencing intermittent "Internal Server Error".

How can I find more information about this error? Any tool can help us pinpoint the cause?

**Update**

From CloudTrail, each API call has an event "CreateNetworkInterface". Many of such API calls have error code "Client.NetworkInterfaceLimitExceeded". What is the cause and solution to this?

According to [this AWS Doc (in Chinese)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html), CloudWatch will not write to log when error is due to insufficient IP/ENI. That explains the increase in error number but no logs in CloudWatch.

**Upate 2**

We have found a scheduled Lambda job which may exhausted IP addresses. We stopped the batch job. But still can't have too many user login to server due to "Client.NetworkInterfaceLimitExceeded" error. I realized that there are many "CreateNetworkInterface" event and few "DeleteNetworkInterface" event. How can I "clean up / reset" all network interface in VPC?

Comment: Internal Server Error means there is a service which is returnung http 500. However it's up to the application to reveal which service. Aren't you able to debug the appplication?

Comment: CloudWatch shows error count when in graph. But it doesn't show any log in cloudwatch either.
When error happens on Prod server, Dev server was fine.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: [Cloud Trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html).

**Long answer with a suggestion**

Assuming your application code is fine, most likely the cause of your 500 error is based on Cognito's initial limitations (e.g., number of calls per user): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html.

AWS suggests to use [Cloud Trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html), for logging Api calls. 
However I would suggest, to prove the limitations first, add some logs around the api call yourself, and in development you could call your app/api with a high number of calls; and most likely you will see the 500 error due to the limitations. 
You could do the following in the terminal:

```
for i in `seq 1 1000`; do curl --cookie SecureCookie=TokenValueFromAWS http://localhost:desirablePort/SecuredPath; done
```

Comment: I've been trying to find Cognito logs in CloudTrail for a couple of hours now but I don't see any. Do I need to be in a specific region or have something enabled in Cognito?

Comment: Looks like you can only use CloudTrail to monitor Cognito in the following regions: Asia Pacific (Tokyo), EU (Ireland), and US East (N. Virginia). If you have an existing User Pool somewhere else, you're out of luck at the moment.

Comment: Is there any update to this? I have my user pool set up in US West (Oregon) region. My users are comparing of unable to login. Is there any way I can check any logs to see what is happening?